# Saving delete information to temp tables using into

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way of using into with delete keyword to save the deleted rows in a temp table in sql server?

Comment: Does the table already exist?

Comment: yes the temp table already exists

Comment: It's already been answered by gbn, but I have a full demo at:  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/

Comment: @granadaCoder Demo is excellent,got more details

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Without using a trigger, the [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause lets you do it

```
-- create if needed
SELECT * INTO #KeepItSafe FROM TheTable WHERE 0 = 1;

--redirect the deleted rows to the temp table using OUTPUT
DELETE TheTable OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO #KeepItSafe WHERE ...;
```

Comment: @MartinSmith I love my eyes completely skipped the first lines.  Comment edited :)

Comment: @gbn Can you please see this thread as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089876/how-to-make-sure-that-the-sp-for-the-same-user-cannot-be-accessed-concurrently/19090531#19090531

Answer (score 0):

I guess my main question is what are you trying to do?

1 - Save a copy of the data before deleting?

Both the SELECT/INTO followed by DELETE or DELETE OUTPUT patterns will work fine.

But why keep the data??

2 - If you are looking to audit the table (inserts, updates, deletes), look at my how to prevent unwanted transactions slide deck w/code - http://craftydba.com/?page_id=880.

The audit table can hold information from multiple tables since the data is saved as XML.  Therefore, you can un-delete if necessary.  It tracks who and what made the change.

3 - If it is a one time delete, I use the SELECT INTO followed by the DELETE.  Wrap the DELETE in a TRANSACTION.  Check the copied data in the saved table.  That way, unexpected deletions can be rolled back.

4 - Last but not least, if you are never going to purge the date from audit table or the copy table, why not mark the row as deleted but keep it for ever?

Many systems like people soft use effective dating to show if a record is no longer active.  In the BI world this is called a type 2 dimensional table (slowly changing dimensions).

***See the data warehouse institute article.***
http://www.bidw.org/datawarehousing/scd-type-2/

Each record has a begin and end date.  All active records have a end date of null.

Again, all the above solutions work.

***The main question is what is the business requirements?***

Sincerely

John

The Crafty Dba

Comment: One valid case of saving deleted data is when you need to archive some data into a separated table.